# how can i share my outlook 2007 calendar with outlook 2003

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2003

is it possible?

can't seem to find it in google

Hi sorry for this late reply. 
This would be on a different computer.

Comment: You don't provide enough information. Are the two versios of Outlook on the same machine ? On the same network ? Etc.

Comment: In deed, there is a lack of info but I understand that he wants to share his Outlook 2007 calender over a 2003 client. Using Exchange, it's a piece of cake but this info is not provided.

Comment: @r0ca: yes you are right, I am going to share the Outlook 2007 to outlook 2003. When you say Exchange, what does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scott Hanselman has a great blog post [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FamilyCalendarManagementSharingLifeBetweenOutlookAndWebCalendarsAndTheMagicOfICalendar.aspx) that demonstrates how to share calendars between similar and dissimilar email clients (like outlook, sharepoint and Google). If you follow his steps, you will be able to "publish" your Outlook 2007 calendar and "consume" the 2007 calendar in Outlook 2003.

Comment: Not a problem, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an MS-Exchange server, you just need to share your calendar (You can see how [on this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DWkM18TJkiw)) and at the other end, the user will be able to add your calendar in his/her own Outlook 2003/2007.

Well, it's as simple as that!

If it does not address your question, please include more detail in your question!

Answer (score 1):

I think perfect and free tool for you to share Outlook calendar with other machine is [CodeTwo Outlook Sync](http://www.codetwo.com/outlook-sync/?sts=1212). I've been using it myself for a few months and very like this app.